# Deadlock: mssqlsystemresource and drop table

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

It's not original questions but I didn't find a answer.
I faced deadlocks. Everytime first locked query looks like:

```
select            
            TABLE_QUALIFIER             = s_cov.TABLE_QUALIFIER,
            TABLE_OWNER                 = s_cov.TABLE_OWNER,
            TABLE_NAME                  = s_cov.TABLE_NAME,
            COLUMN_NAME                 = s_cov.COLUMN_NAME,
            DATA_TYPE                   = s_cov.DATA_TYPE_28,
            TYPE_NAME                   = s_cov.TYPE_NAME_28,
            "PRECISION"                 = s_cov.PRECISION_28,
            "LENGTH"                    = s_cov.LENGTH_28,
            SCALE                       = s_cov.SCALE_90,
            RADIX                       = s_cov.RADIX,
            NULLABLE                    = s_cov.NULLABLE,
            REMARKS                     = s_cov.REMARKS,
            COLUMN_DEF                  = s_cov.COLUMN_DEF,
            SQL_DATA_TYPE               = s_cov.SQL_DATA_TYPE_28,
            SQL_DATETIME_SUB            = s_cov.SQL_DATETIME_SUB_90,
            CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH           = s_cov.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH_28,
            ORDINAL_POSITION            = s_cov.ORDINAL_POSITION,
            IS_NULLABLE                 = s_cov.IS_NULLABLE,
            SS_DATA_TYPE                = s_cov.SS_DATA_TYPE

        from
            sys.spt_columns_odbc_view s_cov

        where
            s_cov.ODBCVER = @ODBCVer and
            s_cov.OBJECT_TYPE <> 'TT' and
            (@table_name is null or s_cov.TABLE_NAME like @table_name) and
            (@table_owner is null or schema_name(s_cov.SCHEMA_ID) like @table_owner) and
            (@column_name is null or s_cov.COLUMN_NAME like @column_name) and
            ( s_cov.SS_IS_SPARSE = 0 OR objectproperty ( s_cov.OBJECT_ID, 'tablehascolumnset' ) = 0 )

        order by 2, 3, 17
```

and 2nd locked query is drop table. It's different tables everytime:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME;
```

Do you know real causes of it or something that can help to resolve or avoid the problem? 
I see nothing in a extended trace log. We use ms sql server 2008 r2...
Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `order by 2, 3, 17` is a deprecated and confusing construct. Use the actual column names (`s_cov.TABLE_OWNER`, `s_cov.TABLE_NAME`, `s_cov.ORDINAL_POSITION`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert This query was generated by ms sql server. How can I edit this query?

Comment: Ah. This query isn't generated by SQL Server as such, but it is part of the internals authored by Microsoft (`sys.spt_columns_odbc_view` is an internal view). So there is no way for you to change this query, and you shouldn't try. The Microsoft developers don't always follow their own rules either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it's my fault. I see another LoginName in the trace log so is it mean that this query was created by LoginName?